# Is possible to hook some callback and then send some event/signal/interrupt from command line to running process

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I have c++ process which is running forever and all data is in memory (not in database). Occasionally I need to change code and deploy new version and I need to stop process but before I need to serialize to file and/or save to database ( I have function inside running class which can do that). How to trigger this function, is possible to hook some callback and then send some event/signal/interrupt from command line ?
( I can use 0mq but and add command inside but I wonder is there more elegant solution to this).

Comment: How about using SIGINT (Ctrl-C), and doing your serialization/save stuff inside the handler?

Comment: `man 3 signal` should give you a quick start on signals. I agree with @brokenfoot that a signal would be the easiest way to trigger an action in your process.

Comment: How about using a worker thread, that can be signaled from the main thread when a request to stop is issued? Worker thread could finish gracefully.

Comment: Otherwise, start-stop-deamon?

Comment: @Vince's answer is a better approach, particularly with C++11's threading capabilities. Signal handlers are quite restricted in what they can *safely* do.

Comment: @brokenfoot, I would avoid doing anything nontrivial in C++ in a signal handler.  You can only use async-signal-safe functions in a signal handler, and even using exceptions (whether or not they escape) is suspect, since I believe some runtimes do un-async-signal-safe things during stack unwinding.  (I know for a fact that one of them acquires a mutex.)  Just about the only thing useful I can think of is setting some `sig_atomic_t` flag that the main loop can probe to detect that the signal fired.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: Separate thread is better but I believe that still requires registering a signal.